# Sync shared folders to local machine in OneDrive for Business

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, onedrive

OneDrive for Business is able to sync files to one's local machine via the OneDrive app.  However, it's not clear how to do this since available tutorials (e.g. from [Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-OneDrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i1Vdn6pSeA)) show steps that aren't available.  The "Add to my OneDrive" button does not appear.  Furthermore, there is no "Shared" folder, but rather a "Shared with me" one.  [image: No good, no good.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple distinct versions of OneDrive, as referenced in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/one-drive-for-business-sync-shared-with-me-files/779a12a3-7330-4b82-a90c-4cb4ffeb9769).  Most importantly, OneDrive for Business is based off of SharePoint software.  The distinction between "Shared" and "Shared with me" folders is one good indicator of what you may be using.  The steps necessary to sync files/folders with you are present [here](https://blogs.office.com/2017/01/24/onedrive-brings-new-file-collaboration-and-management-features-to-the-enterprise/), however it's not very clear.  These instructions *should* be valid for Windows 10, as well, but I've not tested it:

1. Make sure you have the [right version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Which-version-of-OneDrive-am-I-using-19246eae-8a51-490a-8d97-a645c151f2ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
2. The admin for the account may need to [enable users to sync Sharepoint files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-users-to-sync-SharePoint-files-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-22e1f635-fb89-49e0-a176-edab26f69614?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  Though, it's probably easier for you to just try getting it to work first.
3. Go to the "Shared with me" folder, click into the folder you'd like to sync, then click on the Sync button up top.  [image]
4. Your browser will then try to open up your OneDrive client, which will likely require you to hit "OK" on one or more pop-ups from your browser, and possibly provide some login credentials.  Once it's all said and done, you'll get a dialog something like this, which allows you to select what components of the current folder you want to sync.  The base file name and path are automatically chosen.  For a typical Windows system, I think the path should be:
   C:\Users\ *user_name*\ *organization*\ *name of person sharing folder* - *folder name*\ [image]
5. Hit "Start sync" and you should be good to go.